# Are $L^{p}$ spaces a part of Functional Analysis?

Tags: discussion, support, tagging

I recently tagged [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/480383/subspaces-of-lp) question as functional analysis in addition to measure theory and $L^{p}$ spaces. However, I was not completely sure whether functional analysis is an appropriate tag for $L^{p}$ spaces. After some thought, I left the tag so that the question receives more attention.

---

Is it correct to tag question about $L^{p}$ as functional analysis specially when we have a dedicated tag for $L^{p}$?

Comment: Well the functional analysis course I am taking now certainly has the topic "$L^p$ spaces" included....

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, [functional-analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/functional-analysis) is a perfectly acceptable tag for questions about $L^p$ spaces in general, and for that question in particular.  The existence of a specific tag doesn't make a more general one inappropriate.

Comment: So is it true that functional analysts are likely to be well versed with $L^{p}$ spaces?

Comment: @Vishal: I would say so.  But then again, they're a sufficiently fundamental part of analysis that I think almost *any* analyst will be well versed in them.

Comment: Yeah probably true.

Comment: @Vishal Especially the $L^p$ spaces as foundation for the Lorentz and Sobolev spaces are important in functional analysis. It's like matrices for linear algebra I guess...

Comment: @AlexR I did not know that $L^{p}$ is to functional analysis what matrices is to Linear Algebra. I always thought $L^{p}$ being a measure theory topic; especially the techniques.